# Is it possible to query a element in mongoose map by key alone

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

If I have a mongoose schema with a map. Is it possible to query a element in the map by key alone

```
const userSchema = new Schema( {
    
    socialHandles: {
        type: Map,
        of: String
    },
    active: {type:Boolean, default:true}
} );
```

I am able to query and find a user whose social handles has instagram key and instagram key holds a particular value with the below syntax.

```
let user = await User.findOne({ 'socialHandles.instagram': 'jondoe' });
```

I am looking for a way to query and find the instagram ids of user if a key called instagram exists. Something of the below form ie get a user with a social handle instagram ( I would need the value of instagram later on).

```
let user = await User.findOne({ 'socialHandles.instagram': * });  // this is just a wrong syntax to explain what I want to achieve
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `$exists` like this:

```
User.findOne({
  "socialHandles.instagram": {
    "$exists": true
  }
})
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/XE0w2H3yACH)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`exists`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-exists)

```js
let user = await User.findOne().exists('socialHandles.instagram')
```

Answer (score 0):

When I do this

```
await User.findOne().exists('socialHandles.instagram');
```

it returns the entire Map. If someone wants to get the individual item (how I got here) we can do this:

```
const map = await User.findOne();
const user = user.get('socialHandles.instagram');
```

Also using this method we can get the entire Map by omitting .instagram:

```
const user = user.get('socialHandles');
```